# Connect to google classroom from external website/app?

Tags: google-classroom

I need to somehow connect to google classroom from a students perspective, and list all assignments coming up soon. I can't find anything about this in the documentation, but using the google authentication I should be able to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method [**`courses.courseWork.list`**](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) this will return a list of course work that the user is permitted to view.

For the scope, as the document says:

> API requests also require the correct user [scopes](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth). Teachers can view assignments, create assignments, attach links to assignment submissions, and set submission grades. Students can view assignments, attach links to their assignment records, and turn-in and reclaim their submissions. Domain administrators can view coursework, but have no write permissions.

Here's a sample code using appscript, you can just play around with it to familiarize yourself.

```
 function listCourses() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    pageSize: 10
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;
  if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      var course = courses[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.id);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No courses found.');
  }
}
```